# Error When Restoring Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

Here is the situation.  I have restored a database to replace an existing version (need to get it back to yesterday at a certain time).  So I do a `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE, etc...` with no problem.

There are about 16 transaction logs that I need to then restore as well to get the database to the point in time that I need it.  The first `RESTORE LOG` completes with success.  The second one tells me 100% complete, but immediately after that I get this message:

**`An error occurred while processing the log for database 'MyDb'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.`**

What exactly does this mean??  I did some research and it looks like a few things can cause this, and none of the examples/situations I read about had to do with a `RESTORE LOG`.  Does this possibly mean my transaction log backup is corrupt??

Is there any remedy to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the data in the log backup might have been corrupted. Can you restore the next log ok, or do you get an error at that point as well?